# Typescript: EventEmitter or Observable asynchronous calls?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am pretty new to angular but I cannot seem to understand how this seems to be running asynchronously? (if that is whats happening)

I simply wanted to call the `parseData` method in my `batchservice.ts` and store the data into `localStorage` then retrieve the data but it seems that when I'm trying to retrieve it, its always null.

```
  @Output() onUploaded: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  onFileUpload(event: any) {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.uploadFile = event?.target.files[0];
    if (this.uploadFile) {
      this.fileName = this.uploadFile.name
      this.batchService.parseData(this.uploadFile)
    }
    this.onUploaded.emit();
```

```
<batch-upload (onUploaded)="loadStoredData()"></batch-upload>
```

**batchservice.ts**

```
parseData(uploadFile: File) {
    this.upFile = uploadFile
    this.header = (this.header as unknown as string) === 'true' || this.header === true;
    this.ngxCsvParser.parse(uploadFile, { header: this.header, delimiter: ',' })
      .pipe().subscribe({
        next: (result): void => {
          this.csvRow = result;
          for (let i = 1; i < this.csvRow.length; ++i) {
            const rowData =
            {
              'time': this.csvRow[i][0].trim(),
              'name': this.csvRow[i][1].trim(),
              'dob': this.csvRow[i][2].trim(),
              'phone': this.csvRow[i][3].trim(),
              'type': this.csvRow[i][4].trim(),
              'comment': this.csvRow[i][5].trim(),
            }
            localStorage.setItem(("row" + i), JSON.stringify(rowData))
            console.log("localStorage item set")
          }
        },
        error: (error: NgxCSVParserError): void => {
          console.log('Error', error);
        }
      });
  }
```

Running `console.log` always outputs in my `loadStoredData` method before console output in my `parseData`

```
 loadStoredData() {
    console.log("loading stored data!")
    let row = localStorage.getItem('row1');
    let temp = JSON.parse(row!)
    console.log(temp.name)
  }
```

this would be a snippet of my console output:

```
loading stored data!
ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null...
localStorage item set!
```

I dont understand how the output for loading is coming before the localStorage item set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.onUploaded.emit();
```

wrap this with setTimeout() with some delay,

```
setTimeout(() => this.onUploaded.emit(),1000)
```

while js is compiling it will run line by line, so when it sees subscribe(in your case it is there here `this.ngxCsvParser.parse(uploadFile, { header: this.header, delimiter: ',' }) .pipe().subscribe({`  so it will push this in another queue and continue its compiling so this.onuploaded.emit() is executing even before values are set in local storage so , the solution would be setTimeout with some delay should solve the problem

but using settimeout is not optimal solution when you are dealing with large data parsing times might be high and setTimeout may execute even before parsing so you need to some how call this.onUploaded() inside callback function of subscribe maybe using pubsub or move the parsedata function inside component

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought that using setTimeout might be one solution but didnt think it was a proper solution.  
I wanted to confirm that the subscription was causing it to run in another queue. Thank you for the insight!